# Is there a loop in R to open multiple .CSV from a folder, apply a change (e.g. remove specific columns) and save it as a .txt with the same name?

Tags: r, loops, csv, import

I am trying to create a loop that:

1. opens all .csv in my folder (separately)
2. removes the columns 1 to 4 and 7 to 13 from those .csv (separately)
3. saves the edited file (as .csv or as .txt) (separately)

I have tried to use the following function, but it merges all the data:

`library(tidyverse)`

`files <- list.files(".", pattern = ".csv")`

```
``dat <- files %>% 
  map_dfr(
    ~ read_csv(.x) %>% 
      slice(7:nrow(.))
  ) %>% 
  select(-c(1:4, 7:13))``
```

I also tried using: `file_paths <- fs::dir_ls("/directory", pattern = ".csv")`
to open the folders;

but I get Error: [ENOENT] Failed to search directory '/Test2': no such file or directory.
(I set that place as the working directory already and just copy-pasted the path) -I read this might be due to an outdated Windows Version. I'm doing it manually and I know there must be a faster way...

I think this should be easily doable, but I cannot find the answer anywhere.
Thank you very much.

[image: how the folder looks like]

An example of the csv is:

ID,Timestamp,Rec,RTC_TC,A0,A1,Heat,Thot1,Thot2,Tcold1,Tcold2,DT,group

P21,2021/11/26 00:09:00,01,20.25,18,20,off,20.88,21.06,20.25,20.5,2021-11-25T16:09:00.00Z,0_1st

P21,2021/11/26 00:09:01,01,20.25,18,20,off,20.81,21.06,20.25,20.5,2021-11-25T16:09:01.00Z,0_1st

P21,2021/11/26 00:09:01,02,20.25,18,20,off,20.81,21.06,20.25,20.5,2021-11-25T16:09:01.01Z,0_1st

P21,2021/11/26 00:09:01,03,20.25,18,20,off,20.81,21.06,20.25,20.5,2021-11-25T16:09:01.02Z,0_1st

Rows: 7496 Columns: 13
-- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Delimiter: ","
chr  (5): treeID, Timestamp, Rec, Heat, group
dbl  (7): RTC_TC, A0, A1, Thot1, Thot2, Tcold1, Tcold2
dttm (1): DT

```
i Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
i Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
structure(list(ID = c("P21", "P21", "P21", "P21", "P21", 
"P21"), Timestamp = c("2021/11/26 06:39:00", "2021/11/26 06:39:00", 
"2021/11/26 06:39:00", "2021/11/26 06:39:00", "2021/11/26 06:39:00", 
"2021/11/26 06:39:00"), Rec = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", 
"06"), RTC_TC = c(19.75, 19.75, 19.75, 19.75, 19.75, 19.75), 
    A0 = c(-8, -8, -2, -2, -2, -2), A1 = c(-4, -4, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ), Heat = c("off", "off", "off", "off", "off", "off"), Thot1 = c(19.88, 
    19.88, 19.88, 19.81, 19.81, 19.81), Thot2 = c(20.19, 20.19, 
    20.19, 20.19, 20.19, 20.19), Tcold1 = c(20, 20, 19.5, 19.5, 
    19.5, 19.5), Tcold2 = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), DT = structure(c(1637879940, 
    1637879940.01, 1637879940.02, 1637879940.03, 1637879940.04, 
    1637879940.05), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), group = c("6_2nd", "6_2nd", "6_2nd", "6_2nd", "6_2nd", 
    "6_2nd")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), problems = <pointer: 0x00000000176c1c30>)
```

Comment: `map_dfr` returns *one*  data.frame, bound by rows, maybe you want `map`.

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the original file, come up with new name or write into a different directory?

Comment: @DanAdams coming up with a new name/write would be the best, but I can copy my folder so it's also fine to overwrite the original one

Answer (score 1):

Here I suggest using `purrr::walk()` which is designed for iteratively applying a function for it's side effect (e.g. writing a file) without directly creating an output.

This function will read in each file drop the columns to drop you specify and then write it out. There are a few options in the function that you can modify to suit. First, it has no out directory by default but you could set that to wherever you want to save these outputs (e.g. `"./out/"`). It also automatically prepends "new_" to each file name to distinguish from the original. You can change this to `NULL` to just overwrite for example.

For the read/write, I like {vroom} for speed and the API, but you can use `base r` or other options here too according to your preference.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(vroom)
# read file list
files <- list.files(".", pattern = ".csv")
# specify columns to drop
drop_cols <- c(1:4, 7:13)

# function to read, trim, write
f <- function(file, drop_cols, outdir = NULL, prefix = "new_") {
  if (!is.null(outdir)) {
    dir.create(outdir)  
  }
  x <- vroom(file) %>% select(-all_of(drop_cols))
  nm <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(file)
  x %>% vroom_write(paste0(outdir, prefix, nm, ".csv"), delim = ",")
}
# iterate over files
walk(files, ~f(.x, drop_cols = drop_cols))
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks good! Where should I change to avoid the new files to have the data merged? (I mean, the columns 5 and 6 got merged in the new output)

Comment: Do you just want to overwrite or output to new folder?

Comment: Output to a new folder would be better. It's already okay, but the new .csv only has one column instead of two (columns 5 and 6 should remain separated).

Comment: Ok - you can do that with this function. Set `outdir = "./out/"` or similar and `prefix = NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked well. However the new output still has 1 column (5+6 merged), I wish to keep them split.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would happen. In my own tests nothing like that happened. Can you edit your question to share a few lines of an example input and output file  to troubleshoot further?

Comment: Thanks, I added the head and four rows as an example

Comment: This probably has to do with the specific formatting of your file and how it gets read in. I suspect that the columns are getting merged somewhere because of the separator in the file. Can you try adding the output of this to your question: `vroom("file.csv") %>% head() %>% dput()`. Then we can see what exactly is going on.

Comment: Thank you Dan, I edited it already using that.

Comment: Ok that seems to look fine from my end. It subsets to 2 columns. Can you load in one of the put files and share that so we can see what happens to it during the `select()` and `vroom_write()`?

Comment: How do I load one? I think the problem must be in  `x <- vroom(file) %>% select(-all_of(drop_cols))` or `x %>% vroom_write(paste0(outdir, prefix, nm, ".csv"))`; where I am trying to find if there is any way I can specify that the remaining columns remain separated and do not merge. I tried deleting fewer columns but they merged as well.

Comment: `vroom()` is supposed to automatically detect the separator from the file extension, but perhaps it failing here so the columns aren't being separated in the exported file or the separator isn't a comma (`,`). Does it look tab separated? I'll edit the code to explicitly specify the separator.

Comment: Can you share `vroom("file.csv") %>% head() %>% dput()` from one of the output files? That might help to clarify the issue.